# Change WordPress login input type - Hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've changed the way users login on my client's store. They're now using a "social security number", which contains only numbers, instead of username, so I want to change the current username field type `type="text"` to `type="tel"` so it will be easier for mobile users to type it, but I can't find any WordPress hook that allows me to change the username login field type with a function. Can someone give me a hand?

I've allowed the use of this particular number by creating a function hooked to the authenticate. Code: `add_filter('authenticate', 'my_function', 10, 3);`, but can't find any about changing a login field type.

Pic of the field I'm trying to change:
[image]

Comment: I think I'd just hook into `login_footer` and output some JS that changes the field's type

Comment: @ChrisHaas I had thought the same too, good suggestion, probably easier than wiring a Page Template

Comment: WordPress login is not the same as WooCommerce login!, 
You just have to overwrite the following line in the [form-login](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ab1a35719c8719c0065f6053892ca970f7f01deb/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php#L40) template file

Comment: I didn't catch that this was Woo, not enough coffee I guess. I'd still recommend JS for this probably. Looks like `woocommerce_login_form_end` or `woocommerce_after_customer_login_form` if you want to support registration, too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form), you need to use a Page Template to change the HTML of the Login page.

The key function is [wp_login_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/)

While there are no parameters to customise the input type attribute, you can retrieve the `HTML` resulting from that function by setting the `echo` parameter to false.

When you have the resulting HTML in a variable you can use `DOMDocument` or simply a `preg_replace` to change the `type="text"` to `type="tel"` or `type="number"`

Something like this:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'echo' => false
    );
    $html = wp_login_form( $args );
    $html = preg_replace('/your-regex/', 'input type="number"', $html);
    echo $html;
} else { // If logged in:
    wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
    echo " | ";
    wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
}
?>
```

Comment: I've found this quick tutorial in case you've never created a Page template before: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-loginpage/

Comment: Oh, that sucks. My login and registration page are the same (both on /my-account page) and works very well besides having nice effects. Recreating all of it just for this type field detail is not worth it. But thank you very much for your response, at least next time I now i've to create a custom login page ;)